# onTouchListener in adapter ListView make onItemClickListener not running

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I creating custom adapter for my list view. In `getView` method, I set `onTouchListener` for `LinearLayout` in my custom adapter. For some reason, `onItemClickListener` in my listview can't run because of this.
This is my code for my custom adapter `TransactionAdapter` method:

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CTransaction> transactions;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CTransaction> transactions){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return transactions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return transactions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_transaction, parent, false);

        LinearLayout llBackground = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llBackground);

        llBackground.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_clicked));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                    v.performClick();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                    break;
                }

                //Tried to use this but not working
                view.onTouchEvent(event);

                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And this is my `setAdapter` and `onItemClickListener` for ListView:

```
    lvTransaction = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTransaction);
    TransactionAdapter adapter = new TransactionAdapter(this, transactions);
    lvTransaction.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvTransaction.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            final int positionSelected = position;

            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(HistoryActivity.this);
            //Show the AlertDialog
        }
    });
```

Comment: So lets rethink your logic. You set onTouchListener to your LinearLayout and above it i believe you have the listview. and you are wondering why the onItemClickListener does not work?? well i believe its because you set the onTouchListener on the root element which is(LinearLayout) and it affects the listview.

Comment: sorry to not giving the full code, my linear layout is custom adapter layout, not the layout where my listview is located.

Comment: so why dont you use touchlistener on listview to change yours linear layout background?

Comment: i can't get the position of touched item from onTouchListener in ListView..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must return false to propagate the touch event so the click listener can capture the click event so:

```
   llBackground.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_clicked));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                v.performClick();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setBackground(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```