# LongClick Event related to ListView

Tags: android, listview, events, click

While holding down one item, you want to hide the item on the screen.

```
public static void InstanceAceesBarListEvent()
{
    _IA_List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position)
            {
                case 0 :
                    _LongKey_Handler.removeCallbacks(_LongKey_Runnable);
                    break;
        }
    });
}

public static void InstanceAceesBarListLongEvent()
{
    _IA_List.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position)
            {
                case 0 :
                    _LongKey_Handler.post(_LongKey_Runnable);

                    return false;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}


public static Handler _LongKey_Handler = new Handler();
public static Runnable _LongKey_Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("LongKeyHandler", LongKey Event:ok");
        _LongKey_Handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

I did this, but it will run in a few seconds.
Can I get this to happen immediately?

In other words, Right from the moment you press I would like to have this event happen all the time while I hold down the click.

Comment: You [can't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958418/change-long-click-delay) that with provided Event handler . You need to add your own Touch listener implementation for this .

Comment: @ADM What should I do?

Comment: I have no idea what you trying to do here .. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577599/4168607) . It might be helpful.